# How to pass a list from a xaml page to another?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for the best practice on how to pass data from page to page.

In Page A I have a button that fires off Page B.
On Page B I have 6 textboxes that allow the user to enter information. When the user is done, the click on a button stores the information to a list, and brings them back to Page A.

I want to pass that data (list) back to Page A.

I'm looking for the Best practice. What is generally accepted as the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `static` variables or [PhoneApplicationService.Current.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx)? There is already [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, I've seen, it. But does this also work with lists, and how? Could you give an example, because I don't get it...

Comment: I've added sample code - but have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

This question is an exact duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page)

This is the best answer to me.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"] = param
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/view/Page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

then in other page simply

```
var k = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["yourparam"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhoneApplicationService.Current.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx) which will surely work with List:

```
//create Dictionary
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 5 };

// add to Dictionary
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.Add("test", numbers);

// then change in disctionary if already added
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["test"] = numbers;

// retrive from Dictionary
List<int> newList = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["test"] as List<int>;
```

This method has one big advantage - your data will be preserved in Tombstone state.

You can think about using `static` variable (which is accessible through your namespace. You can also follow [this article](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/10/passing-object-to-wp-navigation-service.html) and pass your List by NavigationService - I've written something about that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22516924/2681948).